# Python: pygame.QUIT()

Tags: python, pygame, exit, quit, sys

Just been messing around with pygame and ran into this error.

**CODE:**

```
import sys
import pygame
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 600, 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mike Stamets/Desktop/Mygame/Pygame practice/ScreenPractice.py", line 12, in <module>
    pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
SystemExit
```

I was just trying to set a while loop so that when the red X is pressed then the program will exit. What is going wrong?

Comment: Are you running the program in IDLE? Because normally you don't see that exception, the program simply terminates.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `sys.exit()` raises the `SystemExit` exception, so that's perfectly normal.
For example, try changing your exit call to `sys.exit(1)` and you will see the new exit code reflected in your traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../pygame.py", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(1);
SystemExit: 1
```

In other news, you probably don't need to be explicitly calling `pygame.quit()` - [the documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) suggests letting your program quit in the normal way.

Answer (score 2):

Toggle a bool when you hit escape. Then you can cleanly save data other in places, if needed.

```
done = False
while not done:
    #events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    draw()
```

Answer (score 2):

I recalled four events for a simple music player in python.
The code here below

```
import pygame
from pygame import mixer

pygame.init()
mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
mixer.music.load("song.mp3")
mixer.music.play()

print("Press 'p' to pause 'r' to resume")
print("Press 'q' to quit")
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               running  = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                mixer.music.stop()
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                mixer.music.play()
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                mixer.music.pause()
            if event.key == pygame.K_y:
                mixer.music.unpause()

pygame.QUIT()
```