# Python, How to make the pygame window pop up above everything else

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a program (a reaction program). Everytime I run the opening process the window opens behind all the other windows, which makes it so you can not see the cards uncovered. Can anyone help with this? If the code is required just say.

Also how to make it so when I click the x in top right the program actually closes?

Comment: What operation system are you using?

Comment: windows 10 but school computers use windows 7 so either would be great !

Comment: Check out the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5814202/6220679) which can be used to center or position the window. I'm not sure why but it also seems to bring the window to the front.

Comment: [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13927180/6220679) that demonstrates how to close a pygame window. Please always ask only one question at a time here.

Comment: thankyou very much for your help, worked like a charm